# Create declaration maps from existing .d.ts files and JavaScript sources

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, source-maps, .d.ts

It seems typescript compiler can generate .d.ts files and the source maps (.d.ts.map files) from JavaScript sources as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html).  Declaration maps are generated with `declarationMap` option in `tsconfig.json`.

However, what if I create .d.ts files manually (without using tsc)?  So I have JavaScript source files and .d.ts files that I created manually.  Is there any way to generate declaration maps from these?  How would I go about this?  Can declaration maps be created manually as well?

Comment: Don't source maps map `file.js` breakpoints(equivalent) to `file.ts`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I need, I have a library written in javascript together with .d.ts files.  When debugging typescript application using this library, I need to be able to step into js code of the library.

Comment: I was using [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) to run this program with node, but when trying to step into js i only see minified code.

Comment: Try using "inline sources" or "inline maps" tsconfig compiler settings

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in the typescript application that is using the library, but still the same problem.

Comment: Ah, so you mean the problem with tsx compiling JS code when you don;t need that.

Comment: It actually seems like it works if i don't use tsx but just use debugging configuration like described in [this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging), as long as I add `inlineSourceMap` into tsconfig.json.

Comment: What is strange is that if I remove `inlineSourceMap` from tsconfig.json and try to launch the same configuration, i get an error "Cannot use import statement outside a module".  It seems it is because I m using something like `import module = require('module')` in my application.  But when `inlineSourceMap` is set, that error goes away and i can debug.  It would be nice to get an explanation of why this is happening.

Comment: I guess it adds `--enable-source-maps` that's why I guess

Comment: Thanks.  Still not sure how using source maps gets rid of the module error though.  But it seems like we don't really need .d.ts.map files for debugging.  It is still a question on how to generate .d.ts.map for things like "Go to definition" in VSCode, but at least it is not as critical now.

Comment: Investigating this same issue (https://github.com/skovy/typed-scss-modules/issues/198). Need to generate .d.ts.map files from an existing .d.ts file and an existing .scss file. The types are dynamically generated by the tool from the source file so I have the types and source, but unsure how to generate the map files for the "go to definition" in IDEs